# Print contents of a channel in Go

Tags: go

How can I print the contents of a channel in Go?

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ok := make(chan int)
    ok <- 1
    x := <- ok
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

As I understand, `ok` is a channel which can store an integer value. So, how can I print its contents?

`fmt.Println(ok)` doesn't print the value stored inside the channel.

Thanks.

Comment: An unbuffered channel doesn't store anything by design, so `ok` doesn't contain any data to print.

Comment: Also note that "print contents of a channel" isn't really a thing. Your `fmt.Println` *reads a value from the channel* and prints it. Reading a value from a channel removes it from the channel. [The Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) should provide you a solid foundation on how channels work.

Comment: There are no trivial solutions to print values in a channel without `dequeuing` them. So if you want to just read and print you may read print and write to another channel

Comment: I updated the question. Could you take a look? I stored a value into the channel. Then retrieved the value from the channel and now I'm trying to print it.

Comment: @NeonFlash: you did not store a value into the channel, because the channel cannot store a value. However even if you made it a buffered, there is no language method to read the stored value without receiving out of the channel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Channels `make(chan int)` has implicit size zero ( ref: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)

A channel of size zero is unbuffered. A channel of specified size make(chan int, n) is buffered. See http://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements for a discussion on buffered vs. unbuffered channels. The example at http://play.golang.org/p/VZAiN1V8-P illustrates the difference.

Here, channel `<-ok` or `ok <-` will be blocked until someone processes it (**concurrently**). So, change `ok := make(chan int)` to `ok := make(chan int,1)`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ok := make(chan int, 1)
    ok <- 1
    x := <- ok
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Or concurrently proccess it

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ok := make(chan int)
    go func(){
       ok <- 1
    }()
    x := <- ok
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are trying to write to an unbuffered channel since there are no go routines trying to read from the channel it will reach a deadlock situation

Here is what you can do

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ok := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for x := range ok {
            fmt.Println(x)
        }
    }()
    ok <- 1
    ok <- 3
    ok <- 2
    ok <- 5
    ok <- 3
    ok <- 9
    time.Sleep(1)
}
```

you may find the link to play ground [here](https://play.golang.com/p/we6Y-dNAZ69)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think of any other way than using the debugger. try [**delve**](https://github.com/go-delve/delve)

```golang
> main.main() ./main.go:20 (PC: 0x4b68dc)
    15: func main() {
    16: 
    17:     c := make(chan int,10)
    18:     a:=1
    19:     c<-a
=>  20:     fmt.Println(<-c)
    21: 
    22: 
    23: }
(dlv) p c
chan int {
    qcount: 1,
    dataqsiz: 10,
    buf: *[10]int [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    elemsize: 8,
    closed: 0,
    elemtype: *runtime._type {size: 8, ptrdata: 0, hash: 4149441018, tflag: tflagUncommon|tflagExtraStar|tflagNamed|tflagRegularMemory (15), align: 8, fieldAlign: 8, kind: 2, equal: runtime.memequal64, gcdata: *0, str: 847, ptrToThis: 26368},
    sendx: 1,
    recvx: 0,
    recvq: waitq<int> {
        first: *sudog<int> nil,
        last: *sudog<int> nil,},
    sendq: waitq<int> {
        first: *sudog<int> nil,
        last: *sudog<int> nil,},
    lock: runtime.mutex {
        lockRankStruct: runtime.lockRankStruct {},
        key: 0,},}
(dlv)
```